# Reduce or predict sound latency

Tags: c#, audio, latency

I know that a certain delay between the “play-order” and the actual start of the playback of a sound is inevitable.

However, for my current project, I must be able to start a sound-playback at a certain moment in time. This moment is known, so the solution to the problem is ether to reduce the delay-time as much as possible or to somehow predict the latency and start the sound somewhat earlier (depending on the predicted latency).

I describe the problem in detail here:
https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/662236

My current solution is to use NAudio to play a sound and simultaneously observe the sound-output-volume. This way I can measure the latency and use it to time the “play-order” for the following sounds.

This way I get decent results (about 30 ms deviation from the supposed play-time), but I wanted to ask if you guys have better suggestions.

Best regards and many thanks

Comment: I would begin by finding a library with better documentation.  As in, you know, documentation.

Comment: As stated on the CodePlex project page, it looks like they've moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio), you'd probably be better asking this there.